# Android SQLite Database not functioning

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on my first SQLite database app and after two days of struggling, I'm finally asking the pros for some help.

I'm getting a force close when attempting to display the data  in a text view (`getNurseData` method).  Also, I don't think the `createEntry` method is working either, because after that method is called, I try to clear the EditText controls, with a `setText("");` call but the controls are not clearing.

Here's the `DbCommunicator` class:

```
package com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DbCommunicator {
// create fields for nurses table
public static final String KEY_NURSE_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_LNAME = "_lName";
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "_fName";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "_eMail";
public static final String KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY = "_priPhone";
public static final String KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY = "_secPhone";
public static final String KEY_FTE = "_fte";
public static final String KEY_DUTY_STATUS = "Off Duty"; 

// create fields for rooms table
public static final String KEY_ROOM_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TYPE_PATIENT = "_id";
public static final String KEY_OCCUPIED = "NO";
public static final String KEY_ROOM_NUMBER = "_id";

// database values
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Staffing_Assignments";
public static final String NURSE_TABLE = "Nurse_Table";
public static final String ROOM_TABLE = "Room_Table";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper databaseHelper;
private final Context dbContext;
private SQLiteDatabase sqldb;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // create database if it does not already exist
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + NURSE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_NURSE_ROWID
                + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " + KEY_LNAME
                + "TEXT NOT NULL" + KEY_FNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL" +    KEY_EMAIL
                + "TEXT NOT NULL" + KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY + "TEXT NOT NULL"
                + KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY + "TEXT" + KEY_DUTY_STATUS
                + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ROOM_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROOM_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " + KEY_TYPE_PATIENT
                + " TEXT" + KEY_OCCUPIED + " TEXT NOT NULL" + KEY_ROOM_NUMBER
                + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    } // onCreate

    // upgrade existing database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NURSE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ROOM_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

} // DbHelper class

public DbCommunicator(Context c) {
    dbContext = c;
}

public void close() {
    databaseHelper.close();
}

public DbCommunicator open() throws SQLException {
    databaseHelper = new DbHelper(dbContext);
    sqldb = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public long createEntry(String nurseLname, String nurseFname,
        String nurseEmail, String priPhone, String secPhone, String nurseFTE) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvCreate = new ContentValues();
    cvCreate.put(KEY_LNAME, nurseLname);
    cvCreate.put(KEY_FNAME, nurseFname);
    cvCreate.put(KEY_EMAIL, nurseEmail);
    cvCreate.put(KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY, priPhone);
    cvCreate.put(KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY, secPhone);
    cvCreate.put(KEY_FTE, nurseFTE);

    return sqldb.insert(NURSE_TABLE, null, cvCreate);

}

public String getNurseData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NURSE_ROWID, KEY_LNAME, KEY_FNAME, 
            KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY, KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY };
    Cursor c = sqldb.query(NURSE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NURSE_ROWID);
    int iLname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LNAME);
    int iFname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
    int iEmail = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);
    int iPriPhone = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY);
    int iSecPhone = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY);
    int iDutyStatus = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DUTY_STATUS);


    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + " " + c.getString(iRow) + " "
                + c.getString(iLname) + " "
                + c.getString(iFname) + " "
                + c.getString(iPriPhone) + " " + c.getString(iSecPhone) + " "
                + c.getString(iEmail) + " " + c.getString(iDutyStatus) + "\n";
    }
    c.deactivate();
    c.close();
    return result;
}

}// DbCommunicator class
```

Here's the `NursingAssignments` class that attempts to fill a TextView from the `getNurseData` method:

```
package com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NursingAssignments extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button addNurse;
Button removeNurse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nurse_assignments);
    displayNursingData();

    // set variable values and OnClickListeners
    addNurse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToRoster);
    removeNurse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveFromRoster);
    addNurse.setOnClickListener(this);
    removeNurse.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnAddToRoster:
        Intent add = new Intent("com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.ADDNURSETOROSTER");
        startActivity(add);
        break;

    case R.id.btnRemoveFromRoster:  
        break;
    }
}

public void displayNursingData()
{
    TextView nurseRoster = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLInfo);
    DbCommunicator info = new DbCommunicator(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getNurseData();
    info.close();
    nurseRoster.setText(data.toString());
}

}
```

And here's the `AddNurseToRoster` class, which attempts to add an entry and clear the EditText controls:

```
package com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddNurseToRoster extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button add;
Button cancel;
EditText lastName;
EditText firstName;
EditText eMail;
EditText primaryPhone;
EditText secondaryPhone;
EditText fte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_nurse_to_roster);
    setControlValues();
}

private void setControlValues() {
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
    eMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    primaryPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrimaryPhone);
    secondaryPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSecondaryPhone);
    fte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFTE);

} // setVariableValues

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAdd:
        try {
            String nurseLname = lastName.getText().toString();
            String nurseFname = firstName.getText().toString();
            String nurseEmail = eMail.getText().toString();
            String priPhone = primaryPhone.getText().toString();
            String secPhone = secondaryPhone.getText().toString();
            String nurseFTE = fte.getText().toString();
            DbCommunicator database = new DbCommunicator(this);
            database.open();
            database.createEntry(nurseLname, nurseFname, nurseEmail,
                    priPhone, secPhone, nurseFTE);
            database.close();
            lastName.setText("");
            firstName.setText("");
            eMail.setText("");
            primaryPhone.setText("");
            secondaryPhone.setText("");
            fte.setText("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("An Error Has Occurred");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.btnCancel:
        break;
    }
} // onClickView
}
```

I'm getting this Logcat error, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
08-23 14:31:25.156: E/AndroidRuntime(577): ERROR: thread attach failed
08-23 14:31:32.545: E/Database(583): Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on 0x136ea8 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE Nurse_Table (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _lNameTEXT NOT NULL,_fNameTEXT NOT NULL_eMailTEXT NOT NULL,_priPhoneTEXT NOT NULL,_secPhoneTEXT,Off DutyTEXT NOT NULL);'.
08-23 14:31:32.555: E/AndroidRuntime(583): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement/com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.NursingAssignments}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: CREATE TABLE Nurse_Table (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _lNameTEXT NOT NULL,_fNameTEXT NOT NULL_eMailTEXT NOT NULL,_priPhoneTEXT NOT NULL,_secPhoneTEXT,Off DutyTEXT NOT NULL);
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: CREATE TABLE Nurse_Table (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _lNameTEXT NOT NULL,_fNameTEXT NOT NULL_eMailTEXT NOT NULL,_priPhoneTEXT NOT NULL,_secPhoneTEXT,Off DutyTEXT NOT NULL);
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.DbCommunicator$DbHelper.onCreate(DbCommunicator.java:52)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.DbCommunicator.open(DbCommunicator.java:87)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.NursingAssignments.displayNursingData(NursingAssignments.java:52)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.NursingAssignments.onCreate(NursingAssignments.java:21)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-23 14:31:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  ... 11 more
08-23 14:31:32.575: E/dalvikvm(583): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

DDMS output:

```
[2012-08-23 09:04:17 - StaffingManagement] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2012-08-23 09:04:17 - StaffingManagement] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-08-23 09:05:14 - StaffingManagement] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5556'
[2012-08-23 09:05:14 - StaffingManagement] Uploading StaffingManagement.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2012-08-23 09:05:14 - StaffingManagement] Installing StaffingManagement.apk...
[2012-08-23 09:05:24 - StaffingManagement] Success!
[2012-08-23 09:05:24 - StaffingManagement] Starting activity com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement.MainActivity on device emulator-5556
[2012-08-23 09:05:26 - StaffingManagement] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.deadEddie.staffingmanagement/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: within two day you did this .. good

Comment: check whether your database is created or not via DDMS in android emulator first

Comment: added logcat error output.  Trying to figure out the rest

Comment: added DDMS output.  Is there any other info I can offer to help get through this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all... Your columns inside the create statement should be devided with ","

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + NURSE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_NURSE_ROWID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_LNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_FNAME + "TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PHONE_PRIMARY + "TEXT NOT NULL,"                 + KEY_PHONE_SECONDARY + "TEXT," + KEY_DUTY_STATUS                 + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ROOM_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROOM_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TYPE_PATIENT+ " TEXT," + KEY_OCCUPIED + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_ROOM_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

I don't think that this create statement will work without it...

Comment: thanks for the props dizworld, but it's actually three, one day to build, two days to unscrew.  haha

Comment: While I'm sure the comma's helped, I found some other problems too, including the fact that I used duplicate values for field names.  Accepting your answer because of all the answers & suggestions posted, yours is of course the most correct.  Cheers.  :)